# not able to call method inside dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have created dynamic dll using below code

```
var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var options = new CompilerParameters
    {
        OutputAssembly = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyTestDll.dll")

    };

    string testsource = ""using System;" +
                                "namespace Myclass.GetNames" +
                                "{" +
                                "public class Test1 : IDisposable" +
                                "{" +
                                "public string GivemeNames(int No);" +
                                "}" +
                                "}";";

    provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { testsource });
```

The dll is generated. But when i add this dll in my project, i cant reference method GivemeNames inside that dll. Do i need to add some more information while generating dll?

Comment: which method/library/class does GivenNames come from?

Comment: Is that code copied from your program, or did you "simplify" it? I ask because the given code (in the string there) is not legal, so it won't compile. Specifically you have neither made `GivemeNames` abstract nor given it a method body, either of which is required.

Comment: @JackM it doesnt come from any library. I have created this method so that i can access it. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Nor have you implemented `Dispose`.

Comment: I can't see it in the library, for your info class and method has to be of public accessibility to allow max reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly won't contain the given class because the class cannot be compiled.

Specifically, here's the code you've got in that string, reformatted, but still identical to your code:

```
using System;
namespace Myclass.GetNames
{
    public class Test1 : IDisposable
    {
        public string GivemeNames(int No);
    }
}
```

The errors you should get from trying to compile this code would be:

- 'Test1.GivemeNames(int)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
- 'Test1' does not implement interface member 'System.IDisposable.Dispose()'

So assuming the assembly was created, it certainly won't compile and contain that code.

You should try rewriting the code to this:

```
string testsource = @"
    using System;
    namespace Myclass.GetNames
    {
        public class Test1
        {
            public string GivemeNames(int No) { return ""Names: "" + No; }
        }
    }";
```

This will:

1. Use `@"..."` syntax instead, which makes it easier to write strings over several lines, note the usage of double quotes in there.
2. Drop `IDisposable` support until you're ready to add it (remember to add the `Dispose` method as well)
3. Make sure the method returns something.

Comment: can you add some example code inside that class which is workable?